# split the superhero names with their ages in the given vector

Tags: r

Given this vector:

```
vector <- c("Superman1000", "Batman35", "Wonderwoman240")
```

I want to split the superhero's name and age.

```
df=data.frame(vector= c("Superman1000", "Batman35", "Wonderwoman240"))

library(stringr)
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)

df %>% separate(vector, c("A", "B"))
```

I tried this but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

If the data is same as shown, we can remove all the digits to get super hero name and remove all the non-digits to get their age.

```
df$super_hero <- gsub("\\D", "", df$vector)
df$super_hero_age <- gsub("\\d+", "", df$vector)
```

---

Or with `tidyr::extract`

```
tidyr::extract(df, vector, into = c("name", "age"),regex = "(.*\\D)(\\d+)")

#         name  age
#1    Superman 1000
#2      Batman   35
#3 Wonderwoman  240
```

---

As mentioned by @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1, we can also use `strcapture`

```
strcapture("(.*\\D)(\\d+)", df$vector, 
           proto = data.frame(superhero = character(), age = integer()))
```

Comment: Check out `strcapture` too. You could do something like `strcapture("(.*\\D)(\\d+)", df$vector, proto = data.frame(superhero = character(), age = integer()))`.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 Nice..thanks. I did not know about that function, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `read.csv` from `base R` after creating a delimiter before the numeric part with `sub`

```
read.csv(text = sub("(\\d+)", ",\\1", df$vector), header = FALSE,
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE, col.names = c('name', 'age'))
#        name  age
#1    Superman 1000
#2      Batman   35
#3 Wonderwoman  240
```

---

Or another option is `separate` where we specify a regex lookaround

```
library(tidyr)
separate(df, vector, into = c("name", "age"), sep= "(?<=[a-z])(?=\\d)")
#         name  age
#1    Superman 1000
#2      Batman   35
#3 Wonderwoman  240
```